# Should it add the conjunction "and" between the sentence in bold?

Tags: conjunctions

> ***Tony is 14,Jim is 15***. Tony is younger than Jim.

Comment: When it's implicit who's younger/older/elder from the first statement, what's the purpose of subsequent statement? Is it from a primary school text?

Comment: Where are you using it? Does it need to be very simplistic?

Comment: I don't think in this case that the specific context or purpose matter. This kind of construction does happen, and it makes sense to ask whether it is grammatical and/or why the comma isn't "and".

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to write these out. You have 3 independent clauses: Tony is 14. Jim is 15. Tony is younger than Jim. You can combine independent clauses either with a conjunction like "and" or by using a semicolon. Some examples:

- Tony is 14; Jim is 15. Tony is younger than Jim.
- Tony is 14, but Jim is 15. Tony is younger than Jim.
- Tony is 14, and Jim is 15. Tony is younger than Jim.
- Tony is 14. Jim is 15, so Tony is younger than Jim.
- Tony is 14. Jim is 15, and Tony is younger than Jim.

That is not an exhaustive list, and there could be other ways to get the idea across. But to answer your question, you certainly *can* add an "and", but you don't have to, and it doesn't have to be in your bolded sentence.

Edit: I should note that the way you wrote it is incorrect, as you can't combine two independent clauses using just a comma. You either need to add a conjunction like "and", use a semicolon, or split them up into separate sentences.

More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_clause